# Отправка запроса на сервер - Lua

Tags: lua

Как сделать отправку get запроса на сайт и после получить ответ сервера? Нашел данные, что нужно использовать библиотеку luasocket, но как - не знаю
Сервер возвращает по запросу example.com/lua.php данные, к примеру текст "Hello world", Lua должен получить эти данные и сохранить в переменную для использования в дальнейшем.

Answer (score 3):

Это можно сделать несколькими способами. Например, с использованием [LuaSocket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html):

```
local http = require("socket.http")

local body, code, headers, status = http.request("http://example.com/lua.php")

if body then
    -- запрос выполнился успешно
    print(body) -- в body тело ответа сервера
else 
    -- произошла ошибка
    print(code) -- сообщение об ошибке (например, "сервер на найден") 
end
```

Если запрос выполнился успешно (ответ сервера `404 Not Found` считается успешным), то функция `request` возвращает 4 значения: тело ответа, код ответа, http-заголовки ответа и строку статуса. Если произошла ошибка, то возвращается 2 значения: nil и сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Вместо `if` можно использовать `assert(body, code)`

Answer (score -1):

luasocket блокирует ввод/вывод. Можно использовать resty-http. Или вообще в поиске ввести lua http request и дальше все просто.

`local http = require "resty.http"
local httpc = http.new()
res, err = httpc:request_uri(uri)`

res - таблица, разобрать ее можно вот таким кодом

`for i,v in pairs(res) do
    ngx.say(i..': '..v)
end`

Но стоит отметить, что отработает это все только из под openresty.